# Return first x paragraphs from a string

Tags: php, paragraphs

How can I return the first x paragraphs from a string using PHP? They're seperated by \r\n but can be put into `<p></p>` tags if needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
//split $s into paragraphs
$a = explode("\r\n", $s);

//extract the first $x paragraphs only
$a = array_slice($a, 0, $x);

//rejoin the paragraphs into a single string again
$s = implode('\r\n', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an xml/html environment, and not plain text, you might consider an xml or DOM parser. I'm not a php guy, but this an example dom parser for php: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Generally much more flexible and powerful, with simple API, then doing the parsing yourself.